# Clear Git commits before push

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I committed and then tried to push files that are too large to upload to GitHub.
How can I "clear" this commit in order to be able to make another commit and push it?

Comment: you can use the git reset --soft HEAD^ here head is the head of previous commit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may simply amend your current commit via a soft reset, followed by unstaging the too large files:

```
# from your feature branch
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

This will move the HEAD pointer back one commit, while also staging all the changes from the commit with the too large files.  Then, you may simply unstage all too large files, commit again, and then push:

```
# from feature
git reset -- path/to/toolarge1.ext
git reset -- path/to/toolarge2.ext
git reset -- path/to/toolarge3.ext
# and so on for all large files

git commit -m 'new commit with no large files'
git push origin feature
```

Answer (score 2):

To keep the work use `git reset --soft HEAD~1`.

Use `git reset --hard` if you ever need to remove the changes you've made. You may need to specify the branch however, just use
`git reset --hard origin/<branch-name>`.

Comment: `git revert` would create a new commit... I don't think that the OP is asking fo this

Comment: I removed it from my answer.

Comment: A hard reset probably is _not_ what the OP wants.  That would throw away all the work, along with the large files.

Comment: I also have soft reset in my answer in order to keep the change, I've reformatted my answer.